# How to respond to "My compiler failed to install (or update)"

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

How should I regard questions asking for help on installing or updating compilers and other programming tools?

There are several asking how to fix an update that failed, eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19726632/visual-studio-2008-sp1-update-damaged-configuration-manager. These questions are directly related to programming tools but I feel they are off-topic for Stack Overflow. I think the question should be closed because:

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow ...

but that close reason continues with the words:

> unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Compilers and IDEs really are "*tools used primarily for programming*".

Are questions like this acceptable and if not, what is the best close reason?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, they are on topic.  Problem is, a proper answer is never on topic.

Comment: On the gripping hand: that question was deleted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Yes, these questions are on-topic.

Both the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and the close vote reason *specifically* say that "software tools used primarily for programming" are on-topic. That obviously includes compilers and IDEs.

You say that you feel these are off-topic, but you didn't say why. Let me turn it around and ask you a question. Do you think that people having trouble setting up GCC, Visual Studio, and/or whatever are going to get better help on a Q&A site for programmers who use the same tools, or general experts on using computers?

Do you get the IT department to help you fix configuration problems with Visual Studio? How's that go?

Comment: I get IT to help when I can't install Visual Studio because I don't have administrative access to the computer. Can I ask about that on SO? Just saying, it's not as clear-cut as you state.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Sure. "Is it possible to install Visual Studio without administrative access?" seems perfectly on-topic.  It's specific to the programming tool, and the answer might conceivably go into functionality that is specific to programming.  For example (I'm just making this up; I don't actually know the answer), maybe everything works normally, except that you can't attach to running processes to debug since that requires administrative rights.

Comment: @RyanM Hmm... Five years later, I still think getting IT to help install VS is not on-topic for SO. Also, "Is it possible" Qs rarely go over well, so I'd say encouraging them is something mods should refrain from doing. "How to install Visual Studio without administrative access?" might be on-topic, but that wasn't what my comment was about. It was specifically a rejoinder to Cody's question, "Do you get the IT department to help you fix configuration problems with Visual Studio?" And I don't think that getting better help on a Q&A site for programmers is a good reason to allow Qs on site...

Comment: ... because by that logic recommendation questions should be on-topic, as should hardware questions (programmers work with hardware all the time in the course of programming).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Ah, fair.  I may have misunderstood your comment.  I thought you were referring to installing VS without administrative access more generally.  And you're right, your formulation of the on-topic question about installing VS without administrative access is better than mine.

Answer (score -4):

> How should I regard questions asking for help on installing or updating software in my system?

Forget a moment what the software do, and ask yourself what the task/question is about. It's about installing stuff on your system. If I have a question about installing vim on Debian, I wouldn't ask it on SO. SO is for questions "unique to software development". Installing/updating software on your system is something every power user/admin has to do at some point of time.