# Would asking about a method to install packages in an unstable connection be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, support, scope

I understand that this is related to the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269596/how-to-respond-to-my-compiler-failed-to-install-or-update), but would [e.g.] the following post be within the scope of the site?

> I noticed that python package installators tend to give up early
> whenever you're trying to install a package in an unstable/slow
> connection, and so I wondered if there could be a way to customize
> this behaviour, so as to prevent the component in charge of the
> downloading from shutting down the entire installation altogether when a
> certain number of failed trials is exceeded.

Comment: Sounds fine to me but you should also look around for existing solutions and state what you tried

Comment: This may be more appropriate at the U&L, ServerFault and similar SE sites. I regularly face such problems in my non-programming tasks.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi IMO it would be appropriate at SO, because it involves ways of using or bypassing a package manager, which is an issue specific for programming and not general computing. But indeed as Phil noted there are existing solutions, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270877/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091623/how-to-install-packages-offline, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66802665/install-a-package-manually-by-downloading-it-and-unfolding-into-site-packages.